# Jenkins plugin updates are unavailable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have updated my jenkins server and see the following message for some plugins. I am not sure how to fix this. I looked at the dependencies section for that plugin and I see they are already installed. Not sure what else is missing so I can see the update available. Dependency for this is Mailer which is already installed on my server.

[image]

Comment: As the blue section notes, this may be because the version of your Jenkins instance doesn't meet the plugin's requirement?

Comment: I can't downgrade jenkins. if I uninstall this plugin it has too many dependants.

Comment: Tries downgrading LDAP plugin but that did not help either.

Comment: Latest LDAP plugin requires Jenkins 2.666+. That also means you can't use it if running LTS latest 2.264.x what versions you got?

Answer (score 0):

That is frustrating but you can try uploading plugins manually.
You can download plugins from here [link to plugin storage](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins).
Of course you have to roughly see what version of the plugin goes with your jenkins version.

Once you downloaded 'proper' plugin version, you go to manage plugins, advanced tab and there you can upload the plugin file. After that restart jenkins and check changes. You should really go to manage plugins, updated plugin tab and update selected plugins...

It could be guess work, but I'm sure after a couple of guesses you'll get to the version of Jenkins you have.

You might need to upgrade jenkins.. here are all jenkins war files:
https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/

Last but not least... don't try to fix all dependencies.. fix those you use, rest is optional.